# Itemized Equation

Tags: equations

I am new to latex, so please pardon me if this question seems trivial. I am writing a document and write equations in `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` since I would like the equations to be numbered (and labeled for cross-referencing).

In one part of the document, I need to create four equations (and have them numbered as 3a, 3b, 3c and 3d) as though they are in a list. I am not sure if there is a straightforward way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 9):

To have a set of equations have the same "main" number with an additional index (the a, b, c), you can use the `subequation` environment : surround the equations you want within the environment.

```
\begin{equation}
x+y=z
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
 a = b+c\\
1 + 1 \neq 3\\
\theta + \phi = \text{greek to me}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
```

The result is

[image: equations]

Comment: I was answering just the same; just a minor remark: the `subequations` environment requires the `amsmath` package.