# Graphics equations: put text on equations

Tags: graphics, equations

[image]

I have a big question that I cannot solve by myself.

I would like to add text on my equations, but I like to have some graphics on those.
For instance, I would like to explain why I am doing something, e.g. by saying which theorem/result i am using to get to a precise point on my equation.
However, I don't want to use only text, but emphasizing with graphics and text box linked with some arrows is preferred.

The image you find is similar to what I am thinking.

I thank you for the help

Best

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: try googling `tikzmark site: tex.stackexchange.com`, it should get you pretty close, for example [Label variables of equation using tikz without using itemize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134773)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here, I do it as a compound stacking operation.  The macro `\calloutsym` is the red circle and underarrow; `\callouttext{}` places `\scriptsize` text under `\calloutsym`, where the text can be multi-line with the use of `\\` in the argument; and `\callout{}{}` places the `\callouttext` of the second argument under the first argument.  EDITED so that `\callout` can take an optional argument denoting a different vertical shift than the default `1.5pt` on the red circle (if your circled text is, for example, taller).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\calloutsym{%
  \ensurestackMath{%
  \scalebox{1.7}{\color{red}\stackunder[0pt]{\bigcirc}{\downarrow}}}%
}
\newcommand\callouttext[1]{%
  \def\stacktype{S}\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}\stackText%
  \stackunder{\calloutsym}{\scriptsize\Longstack{#1}}\stackMath%
}
\newcommand\callout[3][1.5pt]{%
  \def\stacktype{L}\stackMath\stackunder[#1]{#2}{\callouttext{#3}}%
}
\begin{document}
\[ K \callout{\subseteq}{by compactness} \bigcup_{J=1}^{n} V_{nJ} \]
\[ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_{x} f_{n} \mathrm{d}\mu 
\callout[1.8pt]{=}{By Monotone\\Convergence Theorem} \int\limits_{x} f \mathrm{d}\mu
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I should point out that, by default, the red circle will not be overlapped by surrounding math text.  However, if the circled item is within text that should not be cleaved apart, the use of `\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}` will present the original math without making allowances for the red circle.

```
\[
 \renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
 \callout[.5pt]{D}{Total\\Derivative}\vec{V}/Dt =  \ldots\quad
 \renewcommand\useanchorwidth{F}
 \callout[.5pt]{D}{Total\\Derivative}\vec{V}/Dt =  \ldots
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! This is rather useful with writing lecture notes. (Btw. shouldn't the ring be pushed down a tiny bit?)

Comment: Also, I think the proper way of typesetting the differential operator is `\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` and the using `\dif`. (Originally, not my idea.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I updated the result to make the default shift a little larger, and make the shift available as an optional argument to `\callout`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Thanks for the tip on the `\dif`.  I'll leave it out of this solution not to distract things, but I'll add it to my "in-house" style.

Answer (score 17):

With `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
K \tikz[baseline]{ \node[draw=red,fill=red!20,anchor=base,circle,inner sep = 0pt]
  (d1) {$\subseteq$}; } \bigcup_{J=1}^{n} V_{nJ}
\qquad \qquad
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_{x} f_{n} \mathrm{d}\mu \tikz[baseline]{ 
    \node[draw=blue,fill=blue!20,anchor=base,circle,inner sep = 0pt] (d2) {$=$}; } \int\limits_{x} f \mathrm{d}\mu
\end{equation}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red,->] (d1) -- +(270:1cm) node[anchor=north,text = black,] {by compactness};
\draw[blue,->] (d2) -- +(270:1cm) node[anchor=north,text = black, align = left] {by monotone \\ convergence theorem};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can bend arrows by `to [in=145,out=235]` instead of `--` in

```
\draw[red,->] (d1) to [in=90,out=235] +(270:1cm) node[anchor=north,text = black,] {by compactness};
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

With [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[customcolors,markings]{hf-tikz}

\tikzset{offset def/.style={
    above left offset={0.015,0.3},
    below right offset={-0.015,-0.12},
  },
  use color/.style={
    offset def,
    set fill color=white,
    set border color=#1,
  },
}

\newcommand{\annotate}[2][]{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[#1,use marker id] (0,0) -- +(270:1cm)
 node[anchor=north,text=black,align=center] {#2};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
K 
\tikzmarkin[use color=red,mark at =0.785]{a}\subseteq\tikzmarkend{a}
\annotate[red,-stealth,font=\footnotesize]{by compactness}
\bigcup_{J=1}^{n} V_{nJ}
\qquad \qquad
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_{x} f_{n} \mathrm{d}\mu 
\tikzmarkin[use color=blue,mark at =0.785]{b}=\tikzmarkend{b}ù
\annotate[blue,-stealth,font=\footnotesize]{by monotone \\ convergence theorem}
\int\limits_{x} f \mathrm{d}\mu
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could start looking at pstricks solutions.  Here is an example of equation and a graph together: (Note: I had to switch my compiler to XeLaTeX to get this to work)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=.5in, bottom=.5in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
The region is rotated around the x-axis, find the volume bounded by: $\displaystyle \quad y=(\,x+1\,)^{2}, \quad y{\,=\,}0, \quad x=1, \quad x=2 $\\\\\\    
\begin{center}
\newrgbcolor{zzttqq}{0.6 0.2 0}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-0.5)(2.5,9.3)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(2.5,9.3)[x,140] [y,-40]
\pscustom[linecolor=zzttqq,fillcolor=zzttqq,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.1]{\psplot{1}{2}{(x+1)^2}\lineto(2,0)\lineto(1,0)\closepath}
\psplot[plotpoints=200]{-0.5}{2.5}{(x+1)^2}
\psline(1,-0.5)(1,4)
\rput[tl](0.1,8.1){$y=(x+1)^{2}$}
\psline(2,-0.5)(2,10)
\end{pspicture*}
\newline
\end{center}

\begin{align*}
\text{Area} &= \int_a^{b} \Bigg[\, \pi\,(\text{\,radius\,})^{2}\; \Bigg] \,dx \\\\
~ &= \int_0^{1} \Bigg[\, \pi\,(\,x^{2}\,)^{2}\; \Bigg] \,dx \\\\
~ &= \int_0^{1} \Bigg[\, \pi\,x^{4}\; \Bigg] \,dx \\\\
~ &= \Bigg[\, \pi\,\frac{\,x^{5}}{5} \;  \Bigg]_0^{1} \\\\
~ &= \Bigg[\, \pi\,\frac{\,1^{5}}{5} \; - \pi\,\frac{0^{5}}{4} \,  \Bigg] \\\\
~ &= \,\frac{\pi}{5} \, - \, 0 \\\\
~ &= \frac{\pi}{5}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Code is from here http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=10757