# Highlighting equation with arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, amsmath, nodes, arrows

I want to create an equation with highlighting as shown bellow.

[image: desired format]
But using following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,trees,positioning}  
\author{Apurba Paul}  
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[baseline,remember picture] \node (#1) {};} 
\tikzset{square arrow/.style={to path={-- ++(-10,-.25) -| (\tikztotarget)}}}  

\begin{gather*}  
  y=\left[\frac{a}{\tikzmark{a}b}\frac{c}{\tikzmark{b}d}\right]\\  
  \tikz[remember picture]{\node(c){1'st part};}\qquad
  \tikz[remember picture]{\node(d){2'nd picture};}
  \tikz{\draw[->](a.south)to (c.north);}
  \tikz{\draw[->](b.south)to (d.north);}   
\end{gather*}  
\end{document}
```

But I am getting this [image]

Comment: It would be great to hace something simple like "underbrace" but with an arrow instead of a brace would be great, instad of a long and confusing code.  

a\cdot \underbrace{a}_{b\text{ times}}\cdots a  

$a\cdot \underbrace{a}_{b\text{ times}}\cdots a$

Comment: Crosslink to related question (in case someone come across this question), [Graphics equations: put text on equations - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140529/graphics-equations-put-text-on-equations)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the options `remember picture` and `overlay` to the connecting drawing commands:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,trees,positioning}  
\author{Apurba Paul}  
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[baseline,remember picture] \coordinate (#1) {};}

\tikzset{
  square arrow/.style={
    to path={-- ++(-10,-.25) -| (\tikztotarget)}
  }
}

\begin{gather*}  
  y=\left[\frac{a}{\tikzmark{a}b}\frac{c}{\tikzmark{b}d}\right]\\[2ex]
  \tikz[remember picture]{\node(c){1'st part};}\qquad
  \tikz[remember picture]{\node(d){2'nd picture};}
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw[->] (a.south)++(.25em,-.3ex) to (c.north) ;
    \draw[->] (b.south)++(.25em,-.3ex) to (d.north) ;
  }  
\end{gather*}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Without tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
y = \bigg[
  \def\stackalignment{r}
  \stackunder{%
    \stackunder{\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}}{\scalebox{2}{$\swarrow$}\,}%
    }{\scriptstyle\mathsf{First~Part}~~}
  \def\stackalignment{l}
  \stackunder{%
    \stackunder{\displaystyle\frac{c}{d}}{\,\,\scalebox{2}{$\searrow$}}%
    }{\scriptstyle~~\mathsf{Second~Part}}
\bigg]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you wished to do it without the `MnSymbol` package, you could use `\rotatebox` to get the tilted arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
y = \bigg[
  \def\stackalignment{r}
  \stackunder{%
    \stackunder{\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}}{%
      \scalebox{1.5}{\rotatebox{-30}{$\downarrow$}}\,}%
    }{\scriptstyle\mathsf{First~Part}~~}
  \def\stackalignment{l}
  \stackunder{%
    \stackunder{\displaystyle\frac{c}{d}}{%
      \,\scalebox{1.5}{\rotatebox{30}{$\downarrow$}}}%
    }{\scriptstyle~~\mathsf{Second~Part}}
\bigg]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While compiling I am getting error  with '\stackMath`. Error is `stackMath.sty not found`

Comment: @Apurba `stackMath` is not a package name, but a command macro of the `stackengine` package.  Does your source code erroneously state `\usepackage{stackMath}`, instead of `\stackMath`?

Comment: Yes that was the problem and after installing `stackengine` it is working.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
$
\displaystyle
\!
\begin{gathered}
y = [\rnode[b]{L}{\frac{a}{b}}\rnode[b]{R}{\frac{c}{d}}]\\[12pt]
\rnode[t]{LT}{\text{First part}}\qquad \rnode[t]{RT}{\text{Second part}}
\psset{nodesep=3pt,arrows=->}
\ncline{L}{LT}\ncline{R}{RT}
\end{gathered}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.  I get errors such as "Undefined control sequence. \ncline{L}{LT}"  and "Undefined control sequence. \pgfsyspdfmark" and "\psset unrecognized command"

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty picture and use the [overpic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic) package to put the different components on specific places in the picture.

At first: create a white empty picture with arbitrarily size, name it empty.jpg and then put it in the same folder like your tex file.

Below is the MWE. You have just to play arround with the coordinates. But beware: there are two coordinate systems. The one from [overpic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic), and the one from tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{subfigure}    
\usepackage{overpic}  
\usepackage{tikz} 


\begin{document}  

\begin{figure}    
\centering  
\subfigure{  
\begin{overpic}[width=5cm,height=5cm]{empty.jpg}\label{eq:equation1}  
\put(45,50){  $y=\left[\frac{a}{b}\frac{c}{d}\right]$ }  
\put(45,30){  

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]  
\draw[->,thin] (0,0) -- (-5,-5);   
\draw[->,thin] (2,0) -- (7,-5);  
\end{tikzpicture}       }  

\put(20,20){1'st part}  
\put(60,20){2'nd picture}  

\end{overpic}           }  
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe a MWE would help the OP. For me, this is more like a comment than an answer as it is not elaborate.

Comment: Instead of (mis-)using `overpic` here with no real image, you could use the `picture` environment directly. This standard LaTeX environment is used by `overpic` internally. However, I would recommend the much newer TikZ package for this. With it you can declare certain parts as nodes and refer to its coordinates afterwards.