# Inline notes vs footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, notes

In latex you can add footnotes and margin annotations but...

How can you easily add notes just in the region of interest, below or above the line?
Maybe it's called "inline" notes.

For example something like this:
[image: example]

or this:
[image]

I mean notes that are also going to be printed, as the rest of the document.

Something simple like "underbrace" but with an arrow instead of a brace would be great.  How?

```
a\cdot \underbrace{a}_{b\text{ times}}\cdots a  

$a\cdot \underbrace{a}_{b\text{ times}}\cdots a$
```

Comment: It's not solved, nobody replied. Any way to do it with Latex or Luatex or with an additional package?.
More information?  Just try to reproduce the sentese above.

Comment: Have you a Idea why nobody replied? Show a compilable, small code (called minimal working example) showing what you have tried so far. Then you will get answers, I guess! And have you searched this side (try `arrow  equation`)? Check for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145670/highlighting-equation-with-arrow

Comment: That link is interesting, I'll try to find the simplest and more general solution .

Comment: Something simple like "underbrace" but with an arrow instead of a brace would be great:  a\cdot \underbrace{a}_{b\text{ times}}\cdots a

Comment: Do you need these notes in a display or a text context? In a text context I would recommend margin notes as otherwise notes would destroy the line spacing.

Comment: @ChristianLindig  I wouldn't mind to break the line spacing sometimes, or I could even let the notes overlap partially the surrounding text, maybe with a different color.

Answer (score 2):

Such things are difficult. Out of the box solution with the todonote package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

Example for a phrase  1 + 1 =\todo[fancyline]{Equal}\hspace{1ex} 2 


\end{document}
```

Which renders:

[image: Arrow with todonotes]

Of course, there are many other ways to put whichever annotations. But the easier way is to use make you annotations into the pdf. For example, under Windows the software »PDF Xchange Viewer« allows to add annotations. There are many others, Master-PDF, PDF-Editor, I stopped following the developments...

Comment: Can you place that note just above the equal sign?

Comment: @skan Sorry, no idea. And the whole thing won't work in math mode.