# How to write the definition of each term in an equation with pointing arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

[image]Can someone help me in writing equation as given  below

`UTMThesis.sty` is given here

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The package UTMthesis.sty will produce the output    %
% of a thesis according to UTM Thesis Manual,          %     
% School of Graduate Studies, 2007.                    %
% Yusof Yaacob, Department of Mathematical Sciences,             %
% Faculty of Science,  Universiti Teknologi Malaysia   %
% 81310 Johor Bahru, Malaysia                          %
% e-mail: yusofby@utm.my                               %
% 24 December 2009                                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX cod for chapter header
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@}   %  \vspace*{15\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ 
      \centering  
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter

      \normalsize 
           \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter 
       \par\nobreak
              \vskip 1.4\baselineskip 
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize     
         \bfseries #1\par\nobreak 
       \vskip 1.4\baselineskip %
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@} % \vspace*{20\p@} %
  {\parindent \z@  
    \centering  
    \normalfont 
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize 
    \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
         \vskip 1.4\baselineskip  
  }}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
%------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for layout
   %\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.2cm}
   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.7cm}   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.46cm} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
   \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm} %  \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm}
   %\setlength{\headheight}{2mm}
    %\setlength{\headsep}{10.175mm}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for 1.5 spacing
   %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{doublespace}
\setstretch{1.5}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  indentation
   \setlength\parindent{.5in}
   \usepackage{indentfirst} %1st line indented after section...
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for space between paragraph
  \makeatletter
    %\setlength{\parskip}{1.5\baselineskip \@plus 3ex
                %  \@minus 2.0ex}
    \setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip \@plus .01ex
                  \@minus .01ex}
   \makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for no hyphenation and right justified
    \hyphenpenalty=10000 \sloppy
    \raggedbottom
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command to get rid of default running head
   \pagestyle{myheadings}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  page number 
%  \makeatletter
%    \renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
%    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hfill\textrm{\thepage}}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}
%    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}  }
%   \makeatother
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

 %For section font
 % \usepackage{sectsty} 
  %  \chapterfont{\centering\normalsize\uppercase}
  %  \sectionfont{\normalsize\uppercase}
   % \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
   % \subsubsectionfont{\itshape\normalsize}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for REFERENCES name
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change vertical space in section and subsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
  {section}%      % the name
  {1}             % the level
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm}    %{0.5cm}    % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
  {subsection}%   % the name
  {2}             % the leve2
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm} %{0.5cm}        % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change horizontal space in section and subsection
% for times romans
   \renewcommand{\thesection} % space between sect. etc.
     {\thechapter.\arabic{section}\hspace{.12in}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection} 
       {\thesection\hspace{-.3cm}.\arabic{subsection} \hspace{-.135cm}} 
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for  TocLoFT
  \usepackage{tocloft}
    %\cftsetrmarg{2.75cm} %    
     \cftsetrmarg{1.5cm} %  
       \cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm} 
       %\cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm}
    \renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % get rid of dots
%Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}        % off tocname
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{.8cm}      % chapter indent
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.3cm}      % section indent
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{3.25cm}  % subsection indent
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.45cm}  % chp number width
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
%-------------------------------------------------------------  
%List of Table
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}  %\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}  
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{} % off lotname
%\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.015cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.1cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             \renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
\cftsetrmarg{3cm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
 %List of Figure
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{} % off lofname
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{-.1cm}      % figure indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for bold caption
\makeatletter
  \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\vskip 10\p@   % caption parameter
       \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1\,\,\,\,\,} #2} %%%%%
       \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize         % caption parameter
           {#1\,\,\,\,\,}  #2\par  % caption parameter
       \else                                   % caption parameter
           \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}  % caption parameter
   \fi}                                            % caption parameter
\makeatother   
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{paralist} %refine list item
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb} % math symbols
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx} % .eps graphic
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lscape} % for landscape
%-------------------------------------------------------------- 
\usepackage{times}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Theorem-Like-Environment
\usepackage{theorem}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter] }
%--------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{proof}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Proof}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Solution}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I can't see an underprice, but perhaps [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522517) allows you to get what you want.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  thank you for the correction.  I changed it. kind regards, Bibigul

Comment: with forest and colortbl

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263480/undersetting-an-arrow-beneath-an-equation and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254028/graphics-equations-put-text-on-top-of-equations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not difficult to create something like this except for punching in the text.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begingroup\larger[4]
\[
\tikzmarknode{n1}{\rho\frac{D\vec V}{Dt}}~=~\tikzmarknode{n2}{-\nabla p}
 + \tikzmarknode{n3}{\rho\vec g}+\tikzmarknode{n4}{\mu\nabla^2\vec V}\]
\endgroup
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,shorten <=1mm,font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
 \begin{scope}[nodes={text width=6.5em,align=left},node distance=1ex]
  \node (e1) {\underline{Total derivative}};
  \node[right=of e1.north east,anchor=north west] (e2) {\underline{Pressure gradient}\\[1em]
     Fluid flows in the direction\dots};
  \node[right=of e2.north east,anchor=north west] (e3) {\underline{Body force term}\\[1em]
     External forces\dots};
  \node[right=of e3.north east,anchor=north west] (e4) {\underline{Diffusion term}\\[1em]
     For a Newtonian fluid\dots};
 \end{scope}     
 \node[below=0.5ex of e1.south] (eq){$=$};
 \node[below=0.5ex of eq] (tot) {$\rho\left[\frac{\partial \vec V}{\partial t}
 +\left(\vec V\cdot\vec\nabla\right)\vec V\right]$};
 \path (tot.south west) -- (tot.south east) coordinate[pos=0.25] (tot1)
  coordinate[pos=0.75] (tot2);
 \node[below left=2ex and 0ex of tot.south,text width=4em,align=left] (c1) 
    {Change of velocity};
 \node[below right=2ex and 0ex of tot.south,text width=4em,align=left] (c2) {Convective term};
 \draw[cyan,-stealth] (c1) -- (tot1);
 \draw[cyan,-stealth] (c2) -- (tot2);
 \begin{scope}[overlay]
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
 {\draw[cyan,-stealth] (e\X) -- (n\X);} 
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}\par

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried but it is not working, It gives an error : Undefined control sequence. \usetikzlibrary

Comment: @Bibigul Did you compile the above example as is?

Comment: Yes, I compiled as it is. Actually, `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}` is not working in any of my Tex file.

Comment: @Bibigul If you have a standard TeX installation containing `tikz`, it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it is working perfectly. I just reinstalled the MikTex.

Comment: There is a fix typo: change of "velosity" :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I know. It looks like Vincent has edited the code and fixed the typo (Thanks!) in the code.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat Thank you so much, now it is working perfectly in any Tex file but when I am using  UTMthesis.sty it gives an error `Too many }'s. \end{figure}` Can you help me? I uploded UTMThesis.sty

Comment: @Bibigul I think this should not happen with any normal style file. It is very hard to debug this because I do not know how you are using this style file. When I add `\usepackage{UTMThesis}` to the above code it crashes regardless of whether I have any of the Ti*k*Z stuff in. You will get the most competent answer if you ask a separate question and attract some package-writing expert to your problem.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes there are many problems in `.sty` actually. but still we have to use it :-(

Comment: @Bibigul This site has many specialists on different subtopics. While I am somewhat comfortable to play with Ti*k*Z I have virtually no experience in package writing, other users have. So if you ask a new question, which is free of charge, some of them may see it and provide you and all others having this problem a beautiful answer, which I cannot do because of lack of experience.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thanks again for the help and suggestions, I asked a new question. hopefully the experts will help me.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting with a combination of maths + colortbl + forest

The first part is to get maths + colortbl on board

And we get ---

[image]

### MWE for the first part

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\definecolor{boxTitle}{HTML}{fff79a}
\definecolor{boxBackground}{HTML}{fffce0}
\definecolor{boxFrame}{HTML}{f1e2b8}

\tcbset{my box/.style={
    enhanced, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colback=boxBackground, colframe=boxFrame,
    coltitle=black, colbacktitle=boxTitle,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.3cm,
                                    yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={
      before upper=\hspace*{0.5cm}, % reserve space for the image
      overlay={
       \node at ([xshift=0.5cm]frame.west)
         {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{bc-dodecaedre}};
      }
    }
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{my box, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}[title=Momentum Equation]
\[
{\rho\frac{D\vec V}{Dt}}~=~{-\nabla p} + {\rho\vec g}+{\mu\nabla^2\vec V }
\]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Will now integrate with forest for the definitions

Requires some study of the book methinks --let me see and revert

### EDIT1

### With forest

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree= {math content,
          parent anchor=children,
          child anchor=parent,
          },
          before typesetting nodes={where n children=0{
                                                         no edge,
                                                         draw,
                                                         densely dotted,
                                                         content/.wrap value={\strut#1},
                                                         rounded corners,
                                                         replace by ={[,circle,fill,no edge,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,append]}  }{}
                                      }
[
{\rho\frac{D\vec V}{Dt}}~=~{-\nabla p} + {\rho\vec g}+{\mu\nabla^2\vec V}
[Total\ Derivative[,phantom]]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The entire equation does not reproduce in the compiled output--only the first derivative comes through--any ideas? -- but was able to get the label part under the eqn-- that made me happy

### EDIT2

I got the entire equation into the `forest` environ by surrounding the `=` with braces `{}`

Before--

```
{\rho\frac{D\vec V}{Dt}}~=~{-\nabla p} + {\rho\vec g}+{\mu\nabla^2\vec V}
```

After--

```
{\rho\frac{D\vec V}{Dt}}{~=~}{-\nabla p} + {\rho\vec g}+{\mu\nabla^2\vec V}
```

[image]

Comment: "The first part is to get maths + colortbl" : currently there is no use of colortbl in your MWE and to be honest I can't imagine how it should help here. Probably you meant tcolorbox? Please comment on that.

Comment: @leandriis yes you are right - actually I meant colortable and used the short form `colortbl` but the actual code used is for tcolorbox - good obsesrvation-- now how to integrate with forest --any suggestions please