# How do i get equation with description in square box?

Tags: beamer

[image: a]

I was struck in getting equation with its description in separate square box or oval or in circle.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528220/197451https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528220/197451

Comment: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/global-nodes/

Comment: please upload your code as a MWE for an answer in detail

Comment: The link in @jsbibra's first comment should be tex.stackexchange.com/a/528220/197451.