# There is a space between label and punctuation/comma when I used \ref{label} command

Tags: labels, ref

I am writing a thesis using my institution's template. However, when I use `\ref{label}` command, there is a spacing after the label and punctuation/comma. My working is as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\let\my@xfloat\@xfloat
\makeatother

\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{UTMThesis, enumerate, amsfonts, longtable, qtree, etoolbox, array, rotating, pgf, tikz, tikz-cd, algorithm, csquotes}

\makeatletter
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{
    \my@xfloat#1[#2]%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \@normalsize \normalsize
}
\makeatother

\allowdisplaybreaks
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix, positioning, shapes, shapes.geometric, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}
\let\openbox\relax
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax

\newcommand*{\qed}{\hfill\ensuremath{\square}}

%-------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{cite}                       % change  cite from [1,2,3] to [1-3] etc for number system
\makeatletter                           % change from
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}     % [1] to 1. etc 
\makeatother                            % in list of references
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\voffset}{-2.1cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-.4cm}  
%--------------------------------------------------------
\font\fiverm=cmr5 
%\input{Pictex.tex} % using pictex
%---------------------------------------------------------
%\pagestyle{plain}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}  
\cfoot{\vspace{-.35cm}\thepage}  % 
\rfoot{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    
    \chapter{INTRODUCTION}
    
    \section{Background and motivation}
    \label{section:background}
    
    In Section \ref{section:background}, we talked about...
        
    \backmatter
\end{document}
```

that produces:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: The problem you've encountered would appear to be caused by some code in `UTMThesis.sty`. Please tell us more about this style file. Is it available online?

Comment: There's probably a `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}\quad}` within `UTMThesis.sty`. Instead the style should use `\@seccntformat` to set the space in the section counter formatting; not set it as part of the representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue when using `UTMThesis.sty` from [How to write the definition of each term in an equation with pointing arrows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528218/5764) That style file has

```
\renewcommand{\thesection} % space between sect. etc.
  {\thechapter.\arabic{section}\hspace{.12in}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection} 
  {\thesection\hspace{-.3cm}.\arabic{subsection} \hspace{-.135cm}}
```

Including the space within the `\thesection` representation makes it carry through to any `\label` and eventually the `\ref` as well. So, instead you'll need to redefine `\thesection` to the following:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```

You can increase the gap between the sectional unit number and title, adjust it via `\@seccntformat`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\qquad}
\makeatother
```

The default space is `\quad` (equivalent to `\hspace{1em}`).