# Circling part of a fraction in equation* mode

Tags: equations, circles

I want to circle the "second half" of a fraction in an equation, like this:

[image: I want to circle y_1 and x_1]

However, after hours of searching, I'm still unable to do this seemingly simple task. 
The current state of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% Circling
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        {m} = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I managed to circle individual parts of the equation with the 'circled' command, but I was unable to reproduce the image above.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Completely unrelated, but `{m}` should just be `m`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140529/graphics-equations-put-text-on-equations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `tikzmark` library.  It has the advantage of not disturbing the typesetting of the equation too much.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  {m} = \frac{y_2 - \tikzmark{top}y_1}{x_2 - \tikzmark{bot}x_1}
\end{equation*}
\tikz[remember picture]{\draw[overlay,red] ($(pic cs:top)!.5!(pic
cs:bot)+(.4em,.2em)$) circle[x radius=1em,y radius=2em];}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I was already using the tikz package for the rest of the document, this solution is very convenient, so I'm going to accept this one as the solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Another solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{postscript}
        m = \frac{y_2 -\pnode[0,1.75ex]{N} y_1}{x_2 -x_1 \pnode[0.25ex,-1ex]{D}}
        \psframe[linecolor=IndianRed, linewidth=0.5pt, framearc=0.5](N)(D)
    \end{postscript}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you like football? True? :-) Perfect.

Comment: @Sebastiano: No, I don't like football! B. t.w. did you solve your problem updating MiKTeX?

Comment: Bernard. I'm still updating MikTeX :-( I have to wait at least half an hour to install it and then I have to load additional fonts. That's bad luck every time. Frankly, I haven't really liked football for at least 8 years.

Comment: @Bernard : the box looks bad, not exactly vertical. I guess there is a \phantom{x_1} to be added somewhere near y_1 in order to have same dimensions on denominator and numerator. I'm not capable to suggest a fix.

Comment: @pzorba75: You're right. This is due to the difference in width of `x` and `y`, so the centres of the `\Rnode`s are not vertically aligned. As  it also involves the beginning of the numerator and the denominator, I don't see how to fix it, so I preferred to replace `\ncbox` with a simple `psframe` – which makes the code a bit simpler.

Comment: You have written `\begindocument` instead of `\begin{document}`

Comment: @F.Pantigny: Oh! yes. I've fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

My English language is bad :-). I hope to solve your question. 
With `[yscale=2]` you have an ellipse with the foci on axes y, and with

```
\draw (1.2,2.7) circle (.4);
```

you can place the ellipse as you want by increasing or decreasing the eccentricity.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2]
\draw (-1,3) node[anchor=north west] {$m=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$};
\draw (1.2,2.7) circle (.4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```