# How to add infographics to an equation?

Tags: graphics, equations

I am happy to write here and add more to this great community. See the next image...
[image]

\footsize{The screenshot had taken from ``Ecuaciones diferenciales con aplicaciones de modelado'' by Dennis G. Zill, 9na edición}.

Well, question is ``How to add that text in sky-blue to an equation?'' D:

Comment: If you `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}`, you can use `\color{SkyBlue}`.

Comment: the question is about the arrows and text, not the color  i wrote it some bad, sorry

Comment: There should be a number of questions on the site discussing this issue.  Here is one of them: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263480/undersetting-an-arrow-beneath-an-equation.  Another https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140529/graphics-equations-put-text-on-equations

Comment: That’s much clearer, thanks.

Comment: thank you all, i will not delete this question, maybe could help. It was good to interact here, good day!

Answer (score 5):

Probably there are already plenty posts of this type. Now it is one more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
Some text before the equation.
\[\frac{\diff^2\tikzmarknode{x}{x}}{\diff \tikzmarknode{t}{t}^2}+16x=0
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}[color=cyan]
 \draw[latex-] (x.north) |- ++ (1em,1em) node[right,yshift=\baselineskip/2,align=left]
  (x1) {unknown function\\ of one variable};
 \draw[latex-] (t.south) |- ++ (1em,-1em) node[right,align=left]
  (t1) {independent variable};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline=(aux.base)]
\node(aux){\vphantom{1}};
\path let \p1=($(x1.north)-(aux.base)$),\p2=($(t1.south)-(aux.base)$) in 
    (0,\y1) (0,\y2);
\end{tikzpicture}\]
Some more text after the equation.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just have to say great thanks by find it out. i did not tried harder (i mean, not lazy just did not find the way; and i want to participate in community here), i use the first words came to my head to find other questions but nothing showed nearly, so well, maybe this one could help anyway to someone that try with this words. Thanks again! good day