# Label variables of equation using tikz without using itemize - followup question

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I have tried to implement a solution I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134773/label-variables-of-equation-using-tikz-without-using-itemize/134778?noredirect=1#comment564009_134778) for my problem. I do however hit a bit of a snatch. If I just add some text above and below of the example, the graph and the text get on top of each other looking like this:

[image]

I have tried to put it in a box using the package `tcolorbox` but that did not help. Below is my code.

Thanks for your help!

---

```
            \documentclass{article}
            \usepackage{amsmath} % loaded automatically by beamer
            \usepackage{tikz}
            \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
            \tikzset{>=stealth}

            \newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base,#1](#2) {#3};}

            \begin{document}
            Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. 
            \begin{equation*}
                \mathcal{A} = (\,\tikzmark{identity}{\texttt{I}} -\tikzmark[red]{G}{\texttt{G}}\,\,\, 
                \tikzmark[blue]{L}{\texttt{L}} - \tikzmark[purple]{C}{\texttt{C }}\,)
            \end{equation*}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =1.5cm]
                \node (identitydescr) [below left=of identity ]{words};
                \draw[,->,thick] (identitydescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (identity);
                \node[red] (Gdescr) [below =of G]{other words};
                \draw[red,->,thick] (Gdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (G);
                \node[blue,xshift=1cm] (Ldescr) [above right =of L]{some words};
                \draw[blue,->,thick] (Ldescr) to [in=45,out=-90] (L.north);
                \node[purple] (Cdescr) [below right =of C]{more words};
                \draw[purple,->,thick] (Cdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (C.south);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. 
            \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `minipage` with suitable height and vertically centered content.

```
            \documentclass{article}
            \usepackage{amsmath} % loaded automatically by beamer
            \usepackage{tikz}
            \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
            \tikzset{>=stealth}

            \newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base,#1](#2) {#3};}

            \begin{document}
            Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it.

\noindent
            \begin{minipage}[t][4.2cm][c]{\linewidth}
            \begin{equation*}
                \mathcal{A} = (\,\tikzmark{identity}{\texttt{I}} -\tikzmark[red]{G}{\texttt{G}}\,\,\,
                \tikzmark[blue]{L}{\texttt{L}} - \tikzmark[purple]{C}{\texttt{C }}\,)
            \end{equation*}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =1.5cm]
                \node (identitydescr) [below left=of identity ]{words};
                \draw[,->,thick] (identitydescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (identity);
                \node[red] (Gdescr) [below =of G]{other words};
                \draw[red,->,thick] (Gdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (G);
                \node[blue,xshift=1cm] (Ldescr) [above right =of L]{some words};
                \draw[blue,->,thick] (Ldescr) to [in=45,out=-90] (L.north);
                \node[purple] (Cdescr) [below right =of C]{more words};
                \draw[purple,->,thick] (Cdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (C.south);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{minipage}

            \noindent
            Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it. Some random text. And more of it.
            \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I can not find the difference between our code samples. Could you check if you posted the right code? Thanks.

Comment: @MatoBehr Sorry my fault. Corrected now..