# Labels with arrows for an equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows

I am trying to adapt the second solution of ["Label variables of the equation using Tikz without using itemize
"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134773/label-variables-of-equation-using-tikz-without-using-itemize) to my equation, `P_t= P_T G_T G_t H_f`.

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
\usecolortheme[named=mygreen]{structure}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=15}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base,#1](#2) {#3};}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Channel model}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> The power coupled into the IC, $P_t$ is
        \end{itemize}
            \begin{equation*}
                P_t = \tikzmark{identity}{P_T} \tikzmark[red]{G}{G_T}\, 
                \tikzmark[blue]{L}{G_t} \tikzmark[purple]{C}{H_f}
            \end{equation*}

            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =1.5cm]
                \node (identitydescr) [below left=of identity ]{transmitted power of the sender};
                \draw[,->,thick] (identitydescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (identity);
                \node[red] (Gdescr) [below =of G]{gain of the transmitter antenna};
                \draw[red,->,thick] (Gdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (G);
                \node[blue,xshift=1cm] (Ldescr) [above right =of L]{gain of the box antenna};
                \draw[blue,->,thick] (Ldescr) to [in=45,out=-90] (L.north);
                \node[purple] (Cdescr) [below right =of C]{attenuation of the transmitted power};
                \draw[purple,->,thick] (Cdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (C.south);
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But it does not work as the linked solution above does. There seem to be several problems in the code, like `tikzmark` does not work with math like `G_T`. Besides, the labels can not break in several lines. I have tried `\\`but it does not work.
I would also like to be able to place the `tikzpicture` in some part below the text. Now it overlies the first text line, or if I put the `tikzpicture` into the itemize environment, the arrows and labels appear displaced.

I would like to know how to control the bend and position of the arrows specified with the in and out angles.

Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

- If you want to use things like `P_T` in the `\tikzmark`, you need math mode
- Your previous definition of `\tikzmark` contained `overlay` as option, this hides the width of the content, thus all your letters were superimposed.
- To get line breaks in your descriptions, you can use pass the `text width` option to the node.

---

And please don't listen to @marmot and accept his answer :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
\usecolortheme[named=mygreen]{structure}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=15}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usepackage{amsmath} % loaded automatically by beamer
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base,#1](#2) {$#3$};}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Channel model}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> The power coupled into the IC, $P_t$ is
    \end{itemize}
        \begin{equation*}
            P_t = \tikzmark{identity}{P_T}\tikzmark[red]{G}{G_T}
            \tikzmark[blue]{L}{G_t}\tikzmark[purple]{C}{H_f}
        \end{equation*}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =1.5cm]
            \node[,text width=2cm] (identitydescr) [below left=of identity ]{transmitted power of the sender};
            \draw[,->,thick] (identitydescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (identity);
            \node[red,text width=2cm] (Gdescr) [below =of G]{gain of the transmitter antenna};
            \draw[red,->,thick] (Gdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (G);
            \node[blue,xshift=1cm,text width=2cm] (Ldescr) [above right =of L]{gain of the box antenna};
            \draw[blue,->,thick] (Ldescr) to [in=45,out=-90] (L.north);
            \node[purple,text width=2cm] (Cdescr) [below right =of C]{attenuation of the transmitted power};
            \draw[purple,->,thick] (Cdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (C.south);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not know the metropolis theme include those options.

Comment: @user1993416 You're welcome! As a rule of thumb: if a theme is divided in color/font/inner/outer theme, the main theme file usually loads all of them.

Answer (score 7):

Your code compiles beautifully if you use the tricks of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402466/121799). But you should really accept [samcarter's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446472/121799). There it is explained why you got the error. [Torbjørn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402466/121799) solves that problem by using `\ifmmode` to check whether the node is in a math environment. I also appended a text width to the nodes of the picture, as suggested by samcarter, and shortened the arrows a bit.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
\usecolortheme[named=mygreen]{structure}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=15}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402466/121799
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{
\ifmmode
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)] \node [inner sep=0pt,#1](#2) {$#3$};
\else
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)] \node [inner sep=0pt,#1](#2) {#3};
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Channel model}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> The power coupled into the IC, $P_t$ is
        \end{itemize}
            \begin{equation*}
                P_t = \tikzmark{identity}{P_T} \tikzmark[red]{G}{G_T}\, 
                \tikzmark[blue]{L}{G_t} \tikzmark[purple]{C}{H_f}
            \end{equation*}

            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =1.5cm,
            every node/.append style={text width=3cm,align=center},
            shorten >=1pt]
                \node (identitydescr) [below left=of identity ]{transmitted power of the sender};
                \draw[,->,thick] (identitydescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (identity);
                \node[red] (Gdescr) [below =of G]{gain of the transmitter antenna};
                \draw[red,->,thick] (Gdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (G);
                \node[blue,xshift=1cm,yshift=-0.6cm] (Ldescr) [above right =of L]{gain of the box antenna};
                \draw[blue,->,thick] (Ldescr) to [in=45,out=-90] (L.north);
                \node[purple] (Cdescr) [below right =of C]{attenuation of the transmitted power};
                \draw[purple,->,thick] (Cdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (C.south);
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can center the equation brute force using `\vfill`. `in` and `out` are just the angles of the ingoing or outgoing path, something like an impact angle and the analog for the outgoing path. By default, Ti*k*Z starts the node at a position that it finds appropriate. You could overrule this e.g. by

```
\draw[->,thick] (identitydescr.north east) to [in=-90,out=90] (identity);
```

but I do not like the result. If you change the impact and outgoing angles

```
\draw[->,thick] (identitydescr) to [in=-45,out=45] (identity);
```

you get

[image]

Another parameter to play with is `looseness`, which gets varied in the animation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
\usecolortheme[named=mygreen]{structure}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=15}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402466/121799
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{
\ifmmode
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)] \node [inner sep=0pt,#1](#2) {$#3$};
\else
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)] \node [inner sep=0pt,#1](#2) {#3};
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0.5,0.6,...,1.2,1.4,...,2}
{\begin{frame}[t]{Channel model}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> The power coupled into the IC, $P_t$ is
        \end{itemize}
        \vfill
            \begin{equation*}
                P_t = \tikzmark{identity}{P_T} \tikzmark[red]{G}{G_T}\, 
                \tikzmark[blue]{L}{G_t} \tikzmark[purple]{C}{H_f}
            \end{equation*}
\vfill
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =1.5cm,
            every node/.append style={text width=3cm,align=center},
            shorten >=1pt,looseness=\X]
                \node (identitydescr) [below left=of identity ]{transmitted power of the sender};
                \draw[,->,thick] (identitydescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (identity);
                \node[red] (Gdescr) [below =of G]{gain of the transmitter antenna};
                \draw[red,->,thick] (Gdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (G);
                \node[blue,xshift=1cm] (Ldescr) [above right =of L]{gain of the box antenna};
                \draw[blue,->,thick] (Ldescr) to [in=45,out=-90] (L.north);
                \node[purple] (Cdescr) [below right =of C]{attenuation of the transmitted power};
                \draw[purple,->,thick] (Cdescr) to [in=-90,out=90] (C.south);
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems we have the same taste for questions to answer at the moment :)

Comment: @samcarter Looks like it... ;-)

Comment: Let's meet again at the next question :)

Comment: @marmot I am using this answer and it works fine. It seems takes the text lines of the labels and break it automatically. I think the result is beautiful. I would like to ask you if it is possible to move the whole tikzpicture to the center of the slide, and also if you could explain about the arrows form (the in out angles) and the length of the arrow. Thanks.

Comment: @user1993416 Do you want to move it vertically of horizontally to the centre?

Comment: @user1993416 I will do that if you promise me to accept samcarters answer.

Comment: @user1993416 Don't listen to @ marmot !

Comment: @marmot I have already accepted samcarter's answer :-)).

Comment: @samcarter Sorry :-)

Comment: @marmot I would like some space below the item text. It will be only one slide in the presentation.

Comment: @user1993416 I updated my answer.

Comment: @marmot I understand. Thank you to `samcarter` and to you.

Comment: @user1993416 And now that you are no longer blackmailed, you can again accept @ marmots answer :)